# Android | AsyncTask - Code is returning incorrect type

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I've been scratching my head at this for too long - any insight would be very beneficial.

This is my first time playing with AsyncTask and I'm a bit confused on what I'm doing wrong here - Eclipse is stating: "This method must return a result of type object" However; I can't see how it's not - unless I'm completely missing something here.

I'm trying to download an image and display it on imageView1 (Also, if you're able to save some time and tell me if I'm running my postExecute code correctly or not that would be great :) )

```
    private class DownloadImageTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Object> {
    protected Object doInBackground(String... urls) {
        try {
            URL url = new URL(urls[0]);
            Object content = url.getContent();
            return content; 
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    protected void onPostExecute(Object result) {
        InputStream is = (InputStream) result;
        Drawable d = Drawable.createFromStream(is, "src");
        ImageView imgView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
        imgView.setImageDrawable(d);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have not returned anything when you are catching exception thats why it is showing message "This method must return a result of type object" .Please **return any object or null** while catching exception.

Moreover if you are getting the drawable than your postexecute method is right.

Your code should look like this:

```
private class DownloadImageTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Object> {
            protected Object doInBackground(String... urls) {
                try {
                    URL url = new URL(urls[0]);
                    Object content = url.getContent();
                    return content; 
                } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    return null;//added 
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    return null;//added
                }
            }
            protected void onPostExecute(Object result) {
                InputStream is = (InputStream) result;
                Drawable d = Drawable.createFromStream(is, "src");
               ImageView imgView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageViewMaricoLogo);
               imgView.setImageDrawable(d);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Ah, that makes sense! I'll try this out as soon as I get home and post the results, thanks-you!

Answer (score 1):

I guess you only want to pass the String(URL) to the AsynTask so your code should be pretty easy like this,

```
private class DownloadImageTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void>
    {

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(String... urls) {
             try {
                    URL url = new URL(urls[0]);
                    Object content = url.getContent();
                    return content; 
                } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            InputStream is = (InputStream) result;
            Drawable d = Drawable.createFromStream(is, "src");
            ImageView imgView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
            imgView.setImageDrawable(d);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Your doInBackground() isn't returning anything, that's why you're getting that error. This happened to me earlier on, set it to return an Object that you will use in onPostExecute or null and it should work. Good luck

Answer (score 0):

Your code should be like this..

```
private class DownloadImageTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {//Notice i changed the Void, and String around in the parameters
protected Object doInBackground(String... urls) {
    try {
        URL url = new URL(urls[0]);
        Object content = url.getContent();
        return content; 
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
    InputStream is = (InputStream) result;
    Drawable d = Drawable.createFromStream(is, "src");
    ImageView imgView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
    imgView.setImageDrawable(d);
}
```

}

EDIT:

I changed the Object to a String. Is this the Object you are trying to return?

Comment: Thanks! But now I'm getting the error that I "must implement AsyncTask<Void, String, Object>.doInBackGround(Void)" - I appreciate the input, but it doesn't seem to be following http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#execute(Params...); or am I still missing something?

Thanks!